# Why is this not valid TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do: declare a variable with `var` on one line, and then export it later.

```
var Game = {};
export Game;
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

> error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

The reason I need this is that I am using Mongoose, where `mongoose.model<Interface>()` creates a model class. I want to add functions to the prototype, and then export it.

Edit: I could do this, but it feels awkward.

```
var _Game = {};
export var Game = _Game;
```

Comment: What happens when you try to compile it?

Comment: error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're exporting a previously declared variable (in both TypeScript and ES6 exports in general), you need to use curly brackets:

```
var Game = {};
export { Game };
```

[Source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-statements)

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
export var Game = {};
```

or

```
var Game = {};
export { Game };
```

reference: [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)